# Help with proving sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $\star$ be a new operator on sets is defined as follows: Given $A$ and $B$, $A \star B=\overline{A \cap B}$.
>
> By using the laws of algebra of sets, show that the following is true:
>
> - $(A \star A) \star (B \star B)=A \cup B$
> - $(A \star B) \star (A \star B)=A \cap B$

I need help with trying to solve the proof for this question.   I just can get my head around where to start.

Comment: For each statement, show that each side of the equation is a subset of the other side.

Comment: Do you know what $A\star{A}$ and $B\star{B}$ equal? Do you know what your universal set is?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE! Here is an outline for the first part:

- $(A \star A) \star (B \star B)=(\overline{A \cap A} )\star(\overline{B \cap B} )=\overline{A} \star \overline{B}=\overline{\bar A \cap\bar B} =\overline{\bar A} \cup  \overline{\bar B}=A \cup B$

Here the fourth equality follows from De Morgan law

Try to prove the other part similarly!